# Can not set property to null but my function is defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

i dont really know how to explain this but i keep getting the eror message "Cannot set properties of null"
im trying to change the innerhtml to the output text.
of the output
i have four functions my button calls but it immediately stops at the first function. the function has worked before but it suddenly stopped.

how do i fix this?

```js
var calories;
var fat;
var saturatedFat;
var salt;
var carbohydrates;
var sugars;
var portionsize;

function getstats() {
    calories = parseFloat(document.getElementById("caloriesinput").value);
    fat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fatinput").value);
    saturatedFat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("saturatedFatinput").value);
    salt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("saltinput").value);
    carbohydrates = parseFloat(document.getElementById("carbohydratesinput").value);
    sugars = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sugarsinput").value);
    portionsize = parseFloat(document.getElementById("portionSizeInput").value);
};
function calculatestats() {
    calories = (calories/100);
    fat = (fat/100);
    saturatedFat = (saturatedFat/100);
    salt = (salt/100);
    carbohydrates = (carbohydrates/100);
    sugars = (sugars/100);
};
function convertstats() {
    calories = (calories*portionsize);
    fat = (fat*portionsize);
    saturatedFat = (saturatedFat*portionsize);
    salt = (salt*portionsize);
    carbohydrates = (carbohydrates*portionsize);
    sugars = (sugars*portionsize);
}

function putstatsout(){
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = ("calories:", calories);
    document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = ("fat:", fat);
    document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = ("saturated fat:", saturatedFat);
    document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML = ("salt:", salt);
    document.getElementById("output5").innerHTML = ("carbohydrates", carbohydrates);
    document.getElementById("output6").innerHTML = ("sugars:", sugars);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>CALculator</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>CALculator</h1>
        <sub>dontadd any commas or dots btw babe</sub>
        <p>calories in 100g</p>
        <input id="caloriesinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>fat in 100g</p>
        <input id="fatinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>saturated fat in 100g</p>
        <input id="saturatedFatinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>salt in 100g</p>
        <input id="saltinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>carbohydrates in 100g</p>
        <input id="carbohydratesinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>sugars in 100g</p>
        <input id="sugarsinput" type="number"></input>
        <hr>
        <p>how many grams(or ml) is the portion?</p>
        <input id="portionSizeInput" type="number"></input>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="getstats();calculatestats();convertstats();putstatsout();">calculate</button>
        <h4>results:</h4>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <span class="output1">....</span>
        <span class="output2">....</span>
        <span class="output3">....</span>
        <span class="output4">....</span>
        <span class="output5">....</span>
        <span class="output6">....</span>          
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script src="script.js"></script>` from `head` tag and move it to end of `body` tag and check if it is working. Basically, you need to check if DOM is loaded using events before using those functions.

Comment: You have `<span class="output6">`, but then use `getElementById("output1")`.    If you want to use class try -> `querySelector('.output6')`.. etc.  `worked before but it suddenly stopped.`, no this would have never worked, you have obviously changed the ID's to class..

Comment: @Keith i used id's because every singel span needed a different output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Keith i used id's because every singel span needed a different
> output.

You can use ID's, or classes, the point I was making your using classes for your output `<span class="output1">....</span>`, and then you try to get a reference to the Element by using an ID., but it doesn't have an ID.

Either use a query selector, eg. `document.querySelector('.output1')`, or change you outputs to use an Id -> `<span id="output1">....</span>`

Below is your snippet using the querySelector option.

> has worked before but it suddenly stopped

No, something changed, it would not have suddenly stopped, unless you changed some code.  I've a gut feeling you changed `<span id="output1">....</span>` into `<span class="output1">....</span>`, but forgot you did it..

```js
var calories;
var fat;
var saturatedFat;
var salt;
var carbohydrates;
var sugars;
var portionsize;

function getstats() {
    calories = parseFloat(document.getElementById("caloriesinput").value);
    fat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fatinput").value);
    saturatedFat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("saturatedFatinput").value);
    salt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("saltinput").value);
    carbohydrates = parseFloat(document.getElementById("carbohydratesinput").value);
    sugars = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sugarsinput").value);
    portionsize = parseFloat(document.getElementById("portionSizeInput").value);
};
function calculatestats() {
    calories = (calories/100);
    fat = (fat/100);
    saturatedFat = (saturatedFat/100);
    salt = (salt/100);
    carbohydrates = (carbohydrates/100);
    sugars = (sugars/100);
};
function convertstats() {
    calories = (calories*portionsize);
    fat = (fat*portionsize);
    saturatedFat = (saturatedFat*portionsize);
    salt = (salt*portionsize);
    carbohydrates = (carbohydrates*portionsize);
    sugars = (sugars*portionsize);
}

function putstatsout(){
    document.querySelector(".output1").innerHTML = ("calories:", calories);
    document.querySelector(".output2").innerHTML = ("fat:", fat);
    document.querySelector(".output3").innerHTML = ("saturated fat:", saturatedFat);
    document.querySelector(".output4").innerHTML = ("salt:", salt);
    document.querySelector(".output5").innerHTML = ("carbohydrates", carbohydrates);
    document.querySelector(".output6").innerHTML = ("sugars:", sugars);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>CALculator</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>CALculator</h1>
        <sub>dontadd any commas or dots btw babe</sub>
        <p>calories in 100g</p>
        <input id="caloriesinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>fat in 100g</p>
        <input id="fatinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>saturated fat in 100g</p>
        <input id="saturatedFatinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>salt in 100g</p>
        <input id="saltinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>carbohydrates in 100g</p>
        <input id="carbohydratesinput" type="number"></input>
        <p>sugars in 100g</p>
        <input id="sugarsinput" type="number"></input>
        <hr>
        <p>how many grams(or ml) is the portion?</p>
        <input id="portionSizeInput" type="number"></input>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="getstats();calculatestats();convertstats();putstatsout();">calculate</button>
        <h4>results:</h4>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <span class="output1">....</span>
        <span class="output2">....</span>
        <span class="output3">....</span>
        <span class="output4">....</span>
        <span class="output5">....</span>
        <span class="output6">....</span>          
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try what Bharat's commented.
Alternatively you can try this:

```
window.onload = () => {
    // your code here
}
```